# How to refresh my table on performing an action without reloading my page in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am able to get the updated data in my table after page reloading. But I should get the data in my table without reloading my page. Please find my code below.

I'm writing a function for approving an entity in a table. SO I'm calling update entity API. After a successful response, I'm trying to get the table again. But it is not happening without refreshing the page.

```
  this.es.updateEntity(data).subscribe(r => {
     this.entity = r;
     this.APIgetAllEntity();   //Calling my api function to reload the table
  })
```

Comment: give us more code, please

Comment: make a manual changedetection after the data has been updated

Comment: will you please create stackblitz so that we can understand your problem bit mroe

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your questions and please correct me if i'm wrong you need to update the table with data after editing row in the table.

i think you have two approach to solve this issue:

1. First you can update only the row which changed.
2. Second you can update the whole table.

First approach :

1. you will need to pass the index of the row from the html so you can update it in your .ts file.

Then you will need to have api that return the data for this single user, or what i like to do is to have the api which will update the user to return the updated data, so you don't need to call any api again.
In your ts:

```
updateUser(id, index){
    this.userServiice.update(id, payload).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.users[index] = res;
    })
}
```

Second Approach:
you can just call the api that return the users (the entire array) and just assign the response to the users array.

Comment: thanks.. The second approach is what we are doing right now. But the datas are not populating without refreshing.. could you solve this?

Comment: could you provide me with your code snippets, so we can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

ngonint only runs once

so if you are create a new MatDataSource on ngoninit it will never update

look into ngchange with an if changes.userData to ensure it doesnt just change data every cycle.